# How to find and read full phrase from text file, when input word. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find and read full phrase from text file, when input word? I'm want to enter word (or many words) and find the phrase in the text file (test.txt) to which it belongs. Where the separation can be any, but in this case it is ";"

test.txt file contains:

```
Soccer ball;round, big and beautiful
TV;a great device for watching TV shows
Coat;red with green lines
Car;very fast and expensive, a rare thing
```

I write "Coat", and I get a phrase from a txt file "red with green lines". And next, right there I can enter any other word and it again will find the right line for me on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
file = open(r'path/to/file')
textlines = file.readlines()
file.close()

dct = {}

for line in textlines:
    before, after = line.split(';')
    dct[before] = after

while True:
    x = input()
    print(dct.get(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could restructure your file to JSON format so that you can read it into Python as a dictionary, then call `dictionary['keyword']` and that will return the sentence you want

Comment: Thank you for help!